# How to Create a class dynamically with its variables and methods in Java?

Tags: java

How to Create a class dynamically with its variables and methods in Java without using Reflections.

I want that the class should be created at runtime with variables like age, name and method like display(String age,String name).

Comment: Why the silly (don't use the obvious tool) requirement?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "Create a class dynamically with its variables and methods in Java"? This could mean a few different things.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [janino](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JANINO/Home), which compiles a String of java code into a class. I have used it to great effect.

Also popular is [Javassist](http://www.csg.is.titech.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/).